# Count row and display count in next row

Tags: csv, powershell, count

I have a list of keys in one row and I am trying to count the rows and add the count number on the next row. I keep getting error. `"Cannot convert value "KEY" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct 
format."` As if it does not like the title of my row in my .csv

My CSV looks like this

```
KEY,
6666,
55555,
5555,
5550,
23,
30,
V-23333
```

My output should be

```
KEY,Count
6666,1
55555,2
5555,3
5550,4
23,5
V-23333,6
```

My code is:

```
 $data = Get-content "file.csv"

 $datalist = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

 $count = 0

 foreach( $KEY in $data) 
 {
     $count++
     $row = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
     $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name KEY -Value $vkey.KEY
     $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Count -Value $count
     $datalist.Add($row)
 } 

 $datalist.ToArray() | Export-CSV "file2.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use select-object to create the Count row:

```
$a = import-csv .\file.csv | select key, count

$count = 1

$a | % { $_.count = $count; $count++} 
$a | Export-Csv .\file2.csv
```

Don't use $ in filename. ($file.csv, $file2.csv)

Comment: yeah the "$" was a typo. I am having issues with the key column I believe... according to the error

Comment: Did you tried the posted Code? Your key isnt alsways a number, like in your last line.

Comment: Yes I tried it. It worked for my count column but the KEY column is blank. You are right the Key is not always a number

Comment: Hm, both in Input and in outpuc csv it looks exactly as requested here.

Comment: is `select key, count` suppose to be the only thing used to call the KEY row or am I supposed to add another line to call it. If so I'm not sure how to assign the row a variable. When I replace what you have for my original count row I still get an error.

Comment: My posted code exactly answers your question/need. If you need to access the key, use `$_.key` inside the foreach loop (%).

Comment: Ok. got it... I didn't realize you had import instead of get-content. Thanks